# Save temporary PDF files in a USB flash from an external app

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a function `save_document()`, **that polls the pressing of a `Extract PDF` button in an external program** and saves a tmp PDF file in a USB drive.

```
import time

import os
import shutil

def save_document():
    print("\n\nPreparing to save the document...", end = "\r")

    TEMP_PDF_DIR = "C:/Users/TUN/tp3/workspace/tmp" # temporary pdfs are stored in this directory

    while not os.listdir(TEMP_PDF_DIR): # wait until the "Extract PDF" button is pressed and a file will be created in directory TEMP_PDF_DIR
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue

    file_path = "C:/Users/TUN/tp3/workspace/tmp" + "/" + os.listdir(TEMP_PDF_DIR)[0]

    shutil.move(file_path, find_drive_id()) # move the file in the USB drive directory 

    print("Document PDF was saved successfully.")
```

And the `find_drive()` function, which looks for a storage device with a given **serial number** and returns its path (path letter like D:, F:, etc.)

```
import wmi

def find_drive_id():
    local_machine_connection = wmi.WMI()

    DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER = "88809AB5" # serial number is like an identifier for a storage device determined by system

    '''.Win32.LogicalDisk returns list of wmi_object objects, which include information
    about all storage devices and discs (C:, D:)'''

    for storage_device in local_machine_connection.Win32_LogicalDisk():
        if storage_device.VolumeSerialNumber == DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER:
            return storage_device.DeviceID

    return False
```

Is there a better way to save a just created temporary PDF file?

Also, the polling loop is bothering me...I believe, there's a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 3):

## General comments

Personally the polling seems fine, a standard way of doing this is using [`watchdog`](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/). I'll just point out some bits and bobs I find odd about your code.

---

**`imports`**

A common way in Python is to split your imports into three sections: builtin modules, community modules and local. So this

```
import time

import os
import shutil
```

Should really be this

```
import time
import os
import shutil
```

Because `time`, `os` and `shutil` all live in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

---

**`descriptive function names`**

Naming this is hard, but it is very important to think carefully about what you name things; especially functions, classes and modules. The main reason why

`save_document()`: and `find_drive_id()`

Are bad names is because they do not do what they say they do. Save document does not save a document, it moves an *already saved* document to a different folder. Similarly `find_drive_id` does not find a drive ID but returns the path to a drive.

---

**`hardcoded paths`**

This is a 2 for 1 deal. First paths are better handled using the [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module (again in the standard library). In addition we are using this path multiple times, so it ought to be extracted into it's own global constant

```
import pathlib

DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = pathlib.PureWindowsPath("c:/Users/TUN/tp3/workspace/tmp")
```

Similarly `DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER = "88809AB5"` should probably be a global constant as well.

---

[**`docstrings`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Triple quotes are usually reserved for [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). In addition this

```
'''.Win32.LogicalDisk returns list of wmi_object objects, which include information
about all storage devices and discs (C:, D:)'''
```

is more of a comment than a quote, and can be converted to `#`. In addition you should add docstrings explaining what each function does.

---

[**`for else`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

This is really nitpicky, but we can write

```
for storage_device in local_machine_connection.Win32_LogicalDisk():
    if storage_device.VolumeSerialNumber == DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER:
        return storage_device.DeviceID
else:
    return False
```

Which I find clearer to read. If we do not break or return in the `for loop` the `else` clause is triggered. You can also think of the `else` as `then`.

---

[**`if __name__ == "__main__":`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Put the parts of your code that are the ones calling for execution behind a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard. This way you can import this python module from other places if you ever want to, and the guard prevents the main code from accidentally running on every import.

## Example code

Here is a mock-up of how a watchdog implementation `could` look. Note that I am on Linux and have no chance to check the details if everything is implemented correctly. However, it ought to be a good starting point =)

```
import time
import pathlib
import shutil

import wmi
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = pathlib.PureWindowsPath("c:/Users/TUN/tp3/workspace/tmp")
# serial number is like an identifier for a storage device determined by system
DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER = "88809AB5"
SLEEP_TIME = 5


class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH
    SLEEP_TIME = SLEEP_TIME

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(self.SLEEP_TIME)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == "created":
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            # move the file in the USB drive directory
            file_path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(event.src_path)
            shutil.move(file_path, get_usb_path())
            print("Document PDF was saved successfully.")


def get_usb_path():
    local_machine_connection = wmi.WMI()
    # Win32.LogicalDisk returns list of wmi_object objects, which include
    # information about all storage devices and discs (C:, D:)
    for storage_device in local_machine_connection.Win32_LogicalDisk():
        if storage_device.VolumeSerialNumber == DRIVE_SERIAL_NUMBER:
            return storage_device.DeviceID
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```